# Retreiving a record from the database WHERE you just need the year/month/day to match

Tags: php, mysql

In my database I have a entry_date that is set as a DATETIME type, how do I go about querying the database for a specific day?  For example if I have a record with 2013-12-27 16:14:10 
and I only really care that I'm getting the record where the 2013-12-27 matches.

Comment: if you compare it to a date it will use 2013-12-27 but you can also use DATE() function to get the date part only for MySQL

Comment: isn't that simple `SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE your_colname='2013-12-27'`

Comment: This will be a phpmyadmin database

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work,.

Comment: @CTully12 phpMyAdmin is not a database. It's a tool written in PHP intended to handle the administration of MySQL.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid No. You need to cast for `date` part.

Comment: SO should give each user some sort of competency exam before granting login.

Comment: @samyi I'm pretty sure this would hurt traffic.

Comment: @samyi No one would ever learn, and having a learning disability that hampers how I word stuff, as well as other effects, I'd be in a world of hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming MySQL, use [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date):

> Extracts the date part of the date or datetime expression.

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE DATE(datecol) = '2013-12-27'
```

Comment: I have attempted to use the above answer however it is returning nothing. My data is set as :: 
entry_date 2013-12-27 00:00:00 
My Query: 
$date = date("Y-m-d" , strtotime("today"));
SELECT * from cheo_whiteboard_staffingOffice WHERE DATE(entry_date)  = ". $date

Comment: FYI, `$date = date("Y-m-d")` is all you need to get today's date.

Comment: What happens if you run that query from the the command line or a tool like phpmyadmin?

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks John, I was missing '' around the variable.